# Highcharts gauge chart customization

Tags: highcharts

I need to display a white line in the middle of the gauge chart like this:
[image]

But I can't find a customization option suitable to do that in Highcharts gauge chart. Can anyone please help?

I don't want the "gauge" arrow. I just want the white separator at 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the separator by using `plotLines` option:

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        value: 100,
        width: 4,
        color: '#fff',
        zIndex: 4

    }],
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1mj80dc6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines